# Long function warning in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I would love PhpStorm to warn my team when the functions they create are too long (e.g. longer than 50 lines of code).
How can I do it?

I found an inspection called 'Overly long function', but it's applied only to Javascript and Typescript, not to PHP.

Any plugins I could use to get such a warning in PHP?
[image]

Comment: PHP Code Sniffer has lots of rules to fine tune by your needs and it is integrated in PHPStorm

Answer (score 0):

Sure

1. `Settings | Editor | Inspections`
2. Then `PHP | Refactoring opportunities`
3. The one you are after is called **Complex function should be refactored** -- it has the LOC (Lines of Code) field. You can also adjust a few other parameters of that inspection.

[image]

PHP Code Sniffer should also have similar stuff (PhpStorm supports it).